# Simple Launchd to run python script

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm running this every minute to debug and it keeps returning with `com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.me.DesktopChanger[16390]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <!-- The label should be the same as the filename without the extension -->
    <string>com.me.DesktopChanger</string>
    <!-- Specify how to run your program here -->
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/python</string>
        <string>~/Library/Application\ Support/DesktopChanger/DesktopChanger.py</string>
    </array>

        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The launchd script is called: `com.me.DesktopChanger.plist`

The python script is located at: `/Users/Tom/Library/Application Support/DesktopChanger/DesktopChanger.py`

and `which python` returns: `/usr/bin/python`

running `ls -l` also returns:

`-rw-r--r--@ 1 Tom  staff  623  6 Feb 13:40 com.me.DesktopChanger.plist`

and the python script with `ls -l` shows:

`-rwxr-xr-x@  1 Tom  staff   672  2 Dec 14:24 DesktopChanger.py`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using a relative path to the script?

```
<string>/Users/Tom/Library/Application\ Support/DesktopChanger/DesktopChanger.py</string>
```

Are you using LaunchControl? I'd recommend using it so you can easily capture Standard Error in the console and see what's underlying abnormal code 2. Without LaunchControl, you can also add these keys to the .plist:

```
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/com.your.thing.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/com.your.thing.out</string>
```

Comment: I tried to add error handling and have tried using relative paths. I'm now getting an error message when I try to unload the Launchd script saying `launchd cannot be run directly`

Comment: Did you try using an absolute path to the script? What is the Standard Error output in the Console? Did you try installing LaunchControl and using that for debugging? It helped me a lot.

Comment: I've tried it with LaunchControl and it states that it is running "Ok" but the python script doesn't seem to execute

Comment: I think I've finally found the issue. The Launchd script is running fine BUT the python script isn't running properly. For whatever reason it runs fine when executed normally but when it is run by the launchd script it doesn't complete.

Answer (score 0):

very late to the party, but it seems you need the Xcode command line tools to allow launchd to run scripts properly, for some reason. Bash scripts work fine without it, but Python seems to need it. After running xcode-select --install my launchd Python scripts run fine.